# Why can't I add a condition and exclude unpublished nodes from search?

Tags: search

I have this code for searching nodes:

```
$index = search_api_index_load("node_index");
$qry = new SearchApiQuery($index);
// $qry->condition('status', '1', '=');
$qry->keys($keywords);
$data = $qry->execute();
$node_results = $data['results'];
```

This code works only if condition is commented. If I uncomment the condition I get a fatal error:

> SearchApiException: Unknown field in filter clause: status. v SearchApiDbService->createFilterCondition() (riadok 1668 z C:\xampp\htdocs\gelightcz\sites\all\modules\search_api_db\service.inc).

What could be wrong?

Comment: Great question. Looking at your code, your doing this correctly. The error suggests that the "status" field doesn't exist as part of the filter. Is it possible that your solr configuration isn't including the node status during index?

Comment: I found something like you said at /admin/config/search/search_api/index/node_index/fields where I checked status field, then renindexed the index and now it works. It is probably what you mean. Thanks.